# How to make a "Find Match" like Mobile Legends or some other MOBA game?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-unet, online-game

I'm trying to create a lobby system that will find a match like other MOBA Games. Like when 10 players is finding a match, it will start the game and when there's only 9 players the system will still wait until it becomes 10.

I used Photon PUN 2 but now I'm using UNet to achieve this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to understand, why did you decide to switch away from Photon? They have a pretty solid lobby system, which supports specific join parameters like max players etc.